# Why strtok_s works when I use StrDup?

Tags: c, windows, string

I use strtok_s with an allocated string.

The code above handles an exception:

```
char *string1 = NULL;
string1 = (char*)LocalAlloc(LPTR, 100 * sizeof(char));
// TODO: Verify if string1 != NULL
string1 = "A string\tof ,,tokens\nand some  more tokens";
token1 = strtok_s(cp1, seps, &next_token1);
```

But when I call StrDup, my code works:

```
cp1 = StrDup(string1);
token1 = strtok_s(cp1, seps, &next_token1);
```

However my understanding of StrDup is it uses LocalAlloc to allocate storage space for the copy of the string (according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759969%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

So, what is wrong in my first example ? How to correct this code without using StrDup ?

Comment: I think you are leaking memory. You have lost the pointer returned by LocalAlloc.

Comment: Ohh my god, this is a rookie mistake ... I was disturbed when I wrote this question. Thank you for the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string1 = (char*)LocalAlloc(LPTR, 100 * sizeof(char));
// TODO: Verify if string1 != NULL
string1 = "A string\tof ,,tokens\nand some  more tokens";
token1 = strtok_s(cp1, seps, &next_token1);
```

You've overwritten your pointer... it starts out NULL and you make it point to allocated space (which is your intention), but you then change it to point to something that is read-only, a c string constant. Since `strtok_s` needs to be able to write into the buffer, this makes it fail. When you `strdup()` instead, you create another (writable) copy of the string.

Instead of setting `string1 = "some constant string";` you can use `strcpy()` (one of its length-limiting versions, for safety) to copy the read only string constant into your buffer. This gets you where you need to be without `strdup()`, but since `strdup()` performs the allocation for you, your work would be easier by going to it directly and cutting out the allocation / copy.

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
string1 = "A string\tof ,,tokens\nand some  more tokens";
```

doesn't do what you expected it to.

You wanted to write the contents of the constant string into the memory buffer pointed to by `string1`.  What you actually did was change the value of `string1` to point at memory that was allocated by the compiler to hold the constant string.

One way of doing what you wanted is

```
strcpy(string1, "A string\tof ,,tokens\nand some  more tokens");
```